# Mosaico and Imagemagick

Tags: civimail

I am trying to test the Mosaico email template plugin however I am getting an error saying that Imagemagick is not install.

I checked with my hosting provider (Siteground) and they say that the PHP library is already install and that the path is /usr/bin/.

However i am not sure how to make Mosaico see that.

Does any one have this plugin working or any advice on how to fix my issue?

Zeak

Answer (score 3):

We got it working after having issues with the imagemagick message - we did have it but needed to install php5-imagick - also we were thrown by being on nginx but alpha had been geared towards apache so a bunch of paths weren't working.

we provided feedback/workarounds at https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/12 which resulted in alpha4 being released. assuming you are using that you might need to open an issue on Veda's github.